# How to get pdf file in response for Magento 2 rest api?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, pdf

Currently **Magento 2** is providing JSON and XML response in web **REST API**
I want to include a custom response format PDF.

So if any third-party will call our API then we can sen them PDF in response.

Answer (score 0):

Just my idea: We shouldn't do this. We can **add the download link or generated link to API response**.
There are some additional points:

- How about your server resource if serving PDF each time calling. Your server can be stress. We should consider about this case.
- Should consider security in this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

First define your route in etc/webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/invoices/:id/pdf/:template" method="GET">
    <service class="Thousandmonkeys\Restpdf\Api\PDFInterface" method="pdf"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

Then in your Model class, which you've defined in di.xml as implementing your interface (in my case Thousandmonkeys\Restpdf\Model\PDFMaker) you can return the generated pdf easily. I've used eadesignro/module-pdfgenerator as my pdf engine (it's rather friendlier than than doing it manually).

```
public function pdf($invoiceId, $templateId){
    $templateModel = $this->pdfGeneratorRepository->getById($templateId);
    if (!$templateModel) {
        throw new \Magento\Sales\Exception(
                __('Could not find template.')
        );
    }
    $invoice = $this->invoiceRepository
        ->get($invoiceId);
    if (!$invoice) {
        throw new \Magento\Sales\Exception(
                __('Could not find invoice.')
        );
    }
    $helper = $this->helper;
    $helper->setInvoice($invoice);
    $helper->setTemplate($templateModel);
    $pdfFileData = $helper->template2Pdf();
    return new PDFResponse(base64_encode($pdfFileData['filestream']));
}
```

PDFResponse is just a class with one getter that magento uses to generate json or xml.

It is a bit heavy so consider load, but it's a trade off between that and using the file system, which is not always a great idea (problems with load balancers & clean up). A respectful client wont cause any more issues with this than anything else. A disrespectful client could just request the pdf over and over.

It would be a bit of a problem to open this up to customers however. You can't guarantee that they will be respectful.

Full implementation https://github.com/lingwooc/restpdf-magento2 or just install thousandmonkeys/m2-restpdf-module